# Google analytics measurement protocol not working for goal conversion

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I made a goal for /phone/ pageview, I am using measurement protocol and using universal analytic for tracking. Report of page view is coming in drill-down report but it's not showing data in goal conversions report list.

data is as below:-

> &v=1&tid=UA-490XXXXXX-1&cid=f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479&t=pageview&dh=powerhandeyman.com&dp=%2fphone%2f%2b16475601035%2f%2b15687895678%2f%2b18765674876%2f5&dt=homepage

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your goal definition? Goals do not care if the data arrived via js code or measurement protocol, so it's possible your problem is with the goal definition. Plus we need to know if you want an exact match for /phone/ or if you want to track everything that starts with /phone/.

Comment: Please find the screenshot at http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/348385/21f0eb85e254e93da27e4c182dc23558, also I want all pages that starts with /phone/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your screenshot your goal definition is looking for exact matches for the string "/phone/". However the document path you are transmitting is

```
dp=/phone/+16475601035/+15687895678/+18765674876/
```

If you want to register a goal for that destinantion you need to change the condition in your goal definition from ""equals" to "begins with".

So this is not actually a problem with the measurement protocol but just a slight misconfiguration in your goal definition.

Comment: I want these goal conversions to the adword for that I have linked account, turned on auto tagging and sharing. I added one more parameter as gclid in the url, This data is coming in the analytics conversions report but not coming in the adword conversion report can you please help me here.

Comment: Thanks, I would never find that Equal filter instead of Begins with would cause the problem just because of the / character at the end.